# label encoder unable to convert a range of categorical columns into numerical columns

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, label-encoding

I have a 50 columns, categorical dataset. Among them only 5 columns are numerical. I would like to apply label encoder to make the categorical columns to numerical columns. Categorical columns are basically nominal columns for my dataset. I need to convert columns 0 to 4 to numerical and column 9 to 50 to numerical values.

I used the command

```
le = LabelEncoder()
df.iloc[:,0:4]=le.fit_transform(df.iloc[:,0:4])
```

df is the name of the dataframe.

error : `ValueError: y should be a 1d array`

How could I fix this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

use `.apply()` method of DataFrame to apply some rule to columns/rows.
In your particular case it will be smth like this: `df.apply(le.fit_transform)` (notice that you need to add `.iloc` here)